# Динамический массив объектов безразмерный - C++ Builder

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Хранить нужно объекты класса в векторе. Как создать динамический массив объектов без указания кол-ва элементов?

```
vector<MyThread*> myVector;
MyThread **myThread = new MyThread*[5];
```

Comment: vector и так выполняет функции динамического массива. Что надо-то, опишите нормально задачу. Пятерка эта вообще откуда?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/  про вектор.

Answer (score 2):

В случае массивов без указания элементов не обойтись. Лучше используйте списки (например `list` или `TList`) или векторы, с методом `push_back`.

Подробнее с примерами можно почитать [здесь](http://edn.embarcadero.com/hr/article/10284) и [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Comment: у меня объекты класса..как создать тогда вектор